# Private key to connect to the machine via SSH must be owned by the user running Vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am trying to follow this [vagrant tutorial](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/). I get error after my first two command. I wrote these two command from command line

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
$ vagrant up
```

After I ran `vagrant up` command I get this message.

```
The private key to connect to the machine via SSH must be owned
by the user running Vagrant. This is a strict requirement from
SSH itself. Please fix the following key to be owned by the user
running Vagrant:

/media/bcc/Other/Linux/vagrant3/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

And then if I run any command I get the same error. Even if I run `vagrant ssh` I get the same error message. Please help me to fix the problem.

I am on linux mint and using virutal box as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear and suggests a solution. You need to set ownership to the `private_key` to the current user.

In the normal situation the following command should be enough:

```
sudo chown `whoami` /media/bcc/Other/Linux/vagrant3/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

---

However in your case it is likely (because of `/media`) that you have placed your project on an external disk. If you use a filesystem that does not support permissions, then either you have to check

```
ls -l /media/bcc/Other/Linux/vagrant3/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

and run `vagrant up` as the user listed as the file owner or move your project elsewhere and assign permissions properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you used NTFS to store Vagrant files please [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856409/9205341) for a workaround the ownership+permission issue.